# URL Result from QR Code Scanner

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

So I'm trying to build a QR Code Scanner, but my result only showing a text. Even the QR Code is have a URL link on it. It can't be open to a browser.

Here's my code for the scanner:

```
public class ReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);
    Button scan_btn = findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
    final Activity activity = this;
    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    }
}}
```

What should I add or change to get clickable URL result? Can someone fix this? Please help me to get my project done. I really need it.

Answer (score 0):

You will get QR results on result.getContents() as soon as you get it you should have to use action intent for view to open URL in browser

Comment: what do you mean by use action intent? I'm sorry I'm still a newbie. I don't really know what the code is and where to put at.

Comment: My result only shown by text. I need when the result is URL, it can be direct to the web browser.

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: Yes man,

first you check that if result contains "http" means URL than please use follow

try {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("Result url"));
    startActivity(myIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No application can handle this request."
        + " Please install a webbrowser",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}